# Inheritance and polymorphism using arrow functions in JavaScript Classes

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, polymorphism, es6-class

Why do arrow functions take precedence over function declarations in JavaScript Classes?

Example :

```
class Parent {

    work = () => {
        console.log('This is work() on the Parent class');
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    work() {
        console.log("This is work() on the Child class ");
    }

}

const kid = new Child();

kid.work();
```

The parent work() method fires in this example :

**"This is work() on the Parent class"**

I just want to understand **WHY** the arrow function always takes precedence in JS Classes, especially in regards to Inheritance and Polymorphism.

Comment: This is [why you should not (ab)use arrow functions in instance class fields as methods](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is nothing to do with being an arrow function. It is taking precedence because it's a [class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). Class fields are added as an **own** property of the instance while methods are added to `Child.prototype.work`. Even if you change it from an arrow function to a regular function, it will still execute the class field.

When you access `kid.work`, the order in which the property will be looked is

- own properties, directly under `kid` object (It is found here)
- `Child.prototype.work`
- `Parent.prototype.work`
- If still not found, it will be looked inside `Object.prototype`

```js
class Parent {
  // doesn't matter if it an arrow function or not
  // prop = <something> is a class field
  work = function() {
    console.log('This is work() on the Parent class');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  // this goes on Child.prototype not on the instance of Child
  work() {
    console.log("This is work() on the Child class ");
  }
}

const kid = new Child();

// true 
console.log( kid.hasOwnProperty("work") )

// true
console.log( Child.prototype.hasOwnProperty("work") )

// false 
// because work inside Parent is added to each instance
console.log( Parent.prototype.hasOwnProperty("work") )

kid.work();

// How to force the Child method
Child.prototype.work.call(kid)
```